# How prove this $\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y-2z}{(x+y)^2+z^2}=0$

Tags: calculus

let $x,y,z\in R$, show that

$$\dfrac{x+y-2z}{(x+y)^2+z^2}+\dfrac{y+z-2x}{(y+z)^2+x^2}+\dfrac{z+x-2y}{(z+x)^2+y^2}=0$$

My idea: let $$x-y=a,y-z=b,z-x=c,a+b+c=0$$

maybe this is very easy,and I think I about more things.

Comment: Why is this tagged inequality?

Comment: Write $$x+y-2z=y-z-(z-x), y+z-2x=z-x-(x-y)$$ then factor out $z-x$ etc.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,yes,I know ,but then ?

Comment: If $x=1,y=2,z=3$, the sum is $-3/18+3/26+0$

Comment: Oh,Thank you.I want use This equation to prove this inequality:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877046/how-prove-this-inequality-frac3x2y2z2xyz22yzxzxy-ge-sum