# How prove this inequality $\frac{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(x+y+z)^2+2(yz+xz+xy)}\ge\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{x^2+(y+z)^2}$

Tags: inequality, fractions

**Question:**

> let $x,y,z\ge 0$.prove or disprove
>
> $$\dfrac{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(x+y+z)^2+2(yz+xz+xy)}\ge\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+(y+z)^2}$$

My idea: let $x+y+z=1$,
then we can only
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+(y+z)^2}=\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{x^2}{2x^2-2x+1}\le\dfrac{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{1+2(xy+yz+xz)}$$

then I can't.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong! Try $x=4$ and $y=z=9$.

Comment: You are not supposed to write this as an answer at all

Comment: @Theodoros Mpalis Try to find a counter example by yourself. It's not so easy. Why I need to post the result of my work in the comment? I don't agree with you!